# Unable to install open ssh server

Tags: 12.04

I am completely new to Ubuntu environment.
I am trying to install open ssh server on my Ubuntu server with 
sudo apt-get install openssh-server

But I am receiving the error as :

```
Some packages could not be installed.This may mean you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
```

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Sri

Comment: Include the full error output from `apt-get`, or the entire `apt-get` output that shows you that error.

Comment: Can you post the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try using `aptitude` instead of `apt-get`:

```
sudo aptitude install <packagename>
```

If you don't have aptitude on your machine, you can get it by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

And try to install OpenSSH again:

```
sudo aptitude install openssh-server
```

Comment: I tried this and still not working :( Serphiroth

Comment: sudo aptitude install openssh-server command was working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --fix-missing
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Comment: when I run sudo apt-get update ; I am receving the Hash Sum Mismatch error. @wb9688

Comment: Please include the full error in the question